# Selecting the appropriate row -- Or get default one

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know If its because I am a beginner or if its because I expect too match from an SQL query, or even if the data don't make sense at all.

**The problem is:**
I have priorities, i.e. if the location is known (in this case =225) to only show the rows with 225, and also if the division is known to show only the 225|5 row. I only want the -1 ones as defaults.

**For example**

If `location=202` and `division=6` to get the `-1|-1`

If `location=225` and `division=6` to get the `225|-1`

If `location=202` and `division=3` to get the `-1|3`

If `location=225` and `division=3` to get the `225|3`

---

The table:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ location ║ division ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║       -1 ║       -1 ║
║       -1 ║        3 ║
║       -1 ║        5 ║
║      225 ║       -1 ║
║      225 ║        3 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM n_comboitems 
WHERE coit_item="PHOLOCOMBO2" 
    AND (coit_location = 225 OR coit_location = -1)
    AND (coit_division = 5 OR coit_division = -1)
```

Which returns

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ location ║ division ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║       -1 ║       -1 ║
║       -1 ║        5 ║
║      225 ║       -1 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

But I want only:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ location ║ division ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║      225 ║       -1 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem?

Comment: I only want one row, in case of known location or division i dont want to get the -1|-1 row.

Comment: You can use if condition in query

Comment: @Alexandros Wouldn't you want 2 rows then? `-1|5` would be fine if the only thing that you don't want is `-1|-1`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro nop I always want one row, if there are two matches but not a 100% one, the location one has priority

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding both an `order by` clause, and a `limit` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM n_comboitems 
WHERE coit_item="PHOLOCOMBO2" 
    AND (coit_location = 225 OR coit_location = -1)
    AND (coit_division = 5 OR coit_division = -1)
ORDER BY coit_location DESC, coit_division DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Ordering in a descending order will push the -1 to the bottom, and the `LIMIT 1` will only return the first row.